# Passing object into Lua function always references self

Tags: lua

I am trying to create an object ("room") in Lua that has a function on it to check if another provided room intersects with it.

I am having an issue where whatever I pass in as a parameter always seems to be the same as the object i am calling the function on.

```
Room = {
    Width = 0,
    Height = 0,
    X = 0,
    Left = 0,
    Right = 0,
    Top = 0,
    Bottom = 0
}

function Room:new(width, height, x, y)
    self.Width = width
    self.Height = height
    self.X = x
    self.Y = y
    self.Left = x
    self.Right = self.X + self.Width
    self.Top = y
    self.Bottom = self.Y + self.Height

    return self
end

function Room:Intersects(other)
    print("Checking for intersection...")
    print("Self X: ", self.X)
    print("Self Y: ", self.Y)
    print("Other X: ", other.X)
    print("Other Y: ", other.Y)
    return other.Left < self.Right and self.Left < other.Right and other.Top < self.Bottom and self.Top < other.Bottom
end

room1 = Room:new(5, 6, 3, 3)
room2 = Room:new(10, 16, 5, 9)

intersects = room1:Intersects(room2)
print("Intersects: ", intersects)
```

Output:

```
$ lua FunctionTest.lua 
Checking for intersection...
Self X:     5
Self Y:     9
Other X:    5
Other Y:    9
Intersects:     true
```

I am expecting `self.X`, `self.Y` to be different from `other.X` and `other.Y`. I have been following Lua.org's chapter on [Object Oriented Programming](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Room is a single table defined at the top, and all references to Room are acting on that *same* table instead of different objects.

The solution below creates a different table called 'obj' and returns this unique table each time that NewRoom() is called.   This approach is loosely similar to chapter 16.4 of the guide you referenced.

```
function NewRoom(width, height, x, y)
    local obj = {
      Width = width,
      Height = height,
      X = x,
      Y = y,
      Left = x,
      Right = x + width,
      Top = y,
      Bottom = y + height,
    }

    function obj:Intersects(other)
      print("Checking for intersection...")
      print("Self X: ", self.X)
      print("Self Y: ", self.Y)
      print("Other X: ", other.X)
      print("Other Y: ", other.Y)
      return other.Left < self.Right and self.Left < other.Right and other.Top < self.Bottom and self.Top < other.Bottom
    end

    return obj
end

room1 = NewRoom(5, 6, 3, 3)
room2 = NewRoom(10, 16, 5, 9)

intersects = room1:Intersects(room2)
print("Intersects: ", intersects)
```

Answer (score 2):

As Dahk says, the Room table you define is the one you also return as the "new" Room object.
`Room:method(...)` is a syntax shorthand for `Room.method(Room, ...)`

The `self` variable provided by Lua contains a reference to Room when you use the shorthand, so when you type `Room:new(5, 6, 3, 3)` what Lua reads is `Room.new(Room, 5, 6, 3, 3)` with `self = Room`. When we then let `self.width = 5` what happens is `Room.width = 5` and that's not what we wanted to happen.

To solve this we need to create a new object every time `Room:new` is called. We create a new table, called obj and then store the values in that.

```
function Room:new(width, height, x, y)
    local obj = {
        Width = width,
        Height = height,
        X = x,
        Y = y,
        Left = x,
        Right = x + width,
        Top = y,
        Bottom = y + height,
    }
    return obj
end
```

This works well, we now can create rooms. But when we try to do `room1:Intersects(other)` we get an error: `method Intersects not defined`. We might have defined a new room, but this room is nothing more than a simple table. This is where metatables come in. Simply put, a metatable defines the behaviour of a table. In our case we want this to contain a for Lua to look when it can't find a value or method in the original list. (See [chapter 13](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.html) for more info on metatables.)

Let's look at an example:
If the floor in each room would be the same, we could either copy this floor to every child, or we let `Room.floor = "Carpet"` and go back to this when someone asks us what the floor in a certain room is. To go back to this we use metatables and the [`__index`](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html) method. This method is that place Lua will look for values it can't find.

```
function Room:new(width, height, x, y)
    local obj = {
        ...
    }
    setmetatable(obj, self) -- self here is equal to Room
    self.__index = self
    return obj
end
```

Again we create the object with all the values we want to store for each room separately. Second, we let `Room` be the metatable for `obj`. The third line tells us that the Room table should be used when any methods can't be found.
The use of `self.__index = self` during the creation of an object would be the same as writing `Room.__index = Room` when defining Room itself, but helps when you just copy the same/similar code every time :)
In case we have defined that `Room.floor = "Carpet"`, the result of `print(room1.floor)` will be Carpet as expected. The value of `room1.floor` is `nil`, then Lua will look for an `__index` in the metatable of room1, where it finds that Room might contain what it was looking for. And indeed, `Room.floor` is defined, so that is what Lua sees as the answer.

### Summary

You can also set a metable and use the `__index` method to define an object as you wished to do. I think it might also be more memory effiecient as you do not define each function seperately for each object of the same class.

---

Also, in case you want to have `Room:Intersects` give false when you do something like `room1:intersects(room1)`, just add `self ~= other`. That only succeeds if `self` and `other` are exactly the same table, even if all the values of the room are the same, they will not be equal and intersect each other.